# How to Check if a String Contains DateTime in Apex?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have a String as below :

```
String str = '<FirstName LastName> - <05-22-2023 08:00:34> - <LongText Description>';
```

I am trying to check if the string contains the datetime as above format. How can we achieve this in apex?

Comment: Hello , please look over this discussion [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69806492/regex-d4-d2-d2) , and try changing your regex pattern .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that gives me the date out of the string :

```
String str = '<FirstName LastName> - <05-22-2023 08:00:34> - <LongText Description>';
String regex = '[0-9]{0,2}-[0-9]{0,2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{0,2}:[0-9]{0,2}:[0-9]{0,2}';

Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
Boolean result= matcher.find();
System.debug('Date is = '+matcher.group(0));
```

Comment: You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. Also, allowing zero digits for month, day, hours, minutes and seconds doesn't make sense. I'd use `{1,2}` instead of `{0,2}`...

Comment: This regex will also match invalid values like `99-99-2023 99:99:99`. You might like to be more restrictive with the leading numbers for most of the date/time components. E.g. `[01]?\d-[0-3]?\d-...`. Of course this doesn't fixe all issues (I could say 39 for the day of month), and you could take it further if you wanted and provide more accurate and complete validation.

Comment: Oh, and while this returns a string, with month, day, year, hours, minutes and seconds, it doesn't actually give you a `Datetime` value...